# Html-css responsive sliding Feedback Form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Slinding Feedback Form isn't responsive at the moment. I've tested it on the phone and the text goes over the screen.
I've changed the CSS *#mrova-feedback* to: *max-with:90%;* still not working.
I have tried nearly everything and my issue is that I can not make it responsive.
What am I doing wrong?
Any thoughts?

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i) {
      var h = $(this).height();
      var oh = $(this).outerHeight();
      var mt = (h + (oh - h)) / 2;
      $(this).css("margin-top", "-" + mt + "px");
      $(this).css("top", "50%");
    });
  };
  $.fn.toggleClick = function() {
    var functions = arguments;
    return this.click(function() {
      var iteration = $(this).data('iteration') || 0;
      functions[iteration].apply(this, arguments);
      iteration = (iteration + 1) % functions.length;
      $(this).data('iteration', iteration);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
$(window).load(function() {
  //cache
  $img_control = $("#mrova-img-control");
  $mrova_feedback = $('#mrova-feedback');
  $mrova_contactform = $('#mrova-contactform');

  //setback to block state and vertical align to center
  $mrova_feedback.vAlign()
    .css({
      'display': 'block',
      'height': $mrova_feedback.outerHeight()
    });
  //Aligning feedback button to center with the parent div 

  $img_control.vAlign()
    //animate the form
    .toggleClick(function() {
      $mrova_feedback.animate({
        'right': '-2px'
      }, 1000);
    }, function() {
      $mrova_feedback.animate({
        'right': '-' + $mrova_feedback.outerWidth()
      }, 1000);
    });

  //Form handling
  $('#mrova-sendbutton').click(function() {
    var url = 'send.php';
    var error = 0;



    $('.required', $mrova_contactform).each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        error++;
      }
    });
    // each
    if (error > 0) {
      alert('Please fill in all the mandatory fields. Mandatory fields are marked with an asterisk *.');
    } else {
      $str = $mrova_contactform.serialize();

      //submit the form
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: $str,
        success: function(data) {

          if (data == 'success') {
            // show thank you
            $('#mrova-contact-thankyou').show();
            $mrova_contactform.hide();
          } else {
            alert('Unable to send your message. Please try again.');
          }
        }
      });
      //$.ajax

    }
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#mrova-feedback {
  display: hidden;
  width: 420px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -462px;
  border: 1px solid #3cb58c;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#mrova-contactform ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mrova-contactform input,
#mrova-contactform textarea {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#mrova-contactform ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#mrova-img-control {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: -52px;
  width: 52px;
  background: transparent url('feedback_buttons/feedback.jpg');
  height: 168px;
}

#mrova-contactform #mrova-sendbutton {
  width: 60px;
  background: #db4f4a;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Feedback Form Demo
  </title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- Files For mRova Feedback Form [Dependency: jQuery] -->
  <script src="mrova-feedback-form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mrova-feedback-form.css" type="text/css" />
  <!-- END -->


  <!-- Just For Demo -->
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      font-family: helvetica, arial, tahoma, verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 40px;
      color: #333;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- END -->
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Free Feedback Form</h1>

  <!--Feedback Form HTML START -->
  <div id="mrova-feedback">
    <div id="mrova-contact-thankyou" style="display: none;">
      Thank you. We'hv received your feedback.
    </div>
    <div id="mrova-form">
      <form id="mrova-contactform" action="#" method="post">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label for="mrova-name">Your Name*</label> <input type="text" name="mrova-name" class="required" id="mrova-name" value="">
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="mrova-email">Email*</label> <input type="text" name="mrova-email" class="required" id="mrova-email" value="">
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="mrova-message">Message*</label>
            <textarea class="required" id="mrova-message" name="mrova-message" rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="mrova-sendbutton" name="mrova-sendbutton">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="mrova-img-control"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Feedback Form HTML END -->


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many things are wrong.
I've tweaked your code and improved it.

The edit was made only on your HTML and CSS.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: helvetica,arial,tahoma,verdana,sans-serif;
 }

h1{
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 40px;
 color: #333;
}
input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    resize: vertical;
}

label {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #db4f4a;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*background-color: #f2f2f2;*/
    padding: 20px;
    display: hidden;
    /*width: 420px;*/
    /*position: fixed;*/
    /*right: -462px;*/
    border: 1px solid #3cb58c;
    /*padding: 8px 20px;*/
    background-color: #fff;
}

.col-25 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75 {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>ReFree Feedback Form</h1>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="fname">First Name*</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="lname">Last Name*</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="message">Message*</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write youre message.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Well forget my HTML & CSS code**

**the problem in this script:**

```
$img_control.vAlign()
    //animate the form
    .toggleClick(function() {
      $mrova_feedback.animate({
         'right': '-2px'
      }, 1000);
    }, function() {
      $mrova_feedback.animate({
        'right': '-' + $mrova_feedback.outerWidth()
      }, 1000);
    });
```

**The script after modification:**

You must change the value of `'right': '-2px'`.
I think -120 is very appropriate, try it and tell me the result.

```
$img_control.vAlign()
        //animate the form
        .toggleClick(function() {
          $mrova_feedback.animate({
             'right': '-120px'
          }, 1000);
        }, function() {
          $mrova_feedback.animate({
            'right': '-' + $mrova_feedback.outerWidth()
          }, 1000);
        });
```

**Do not forget this tag to make the page responsive :**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This tag should be in `<head>`

Comment: Thank you but what about the image control?
Here is a demo [link](http://www.mrova.com/feedbackForm/index.html)[/link).
The problem is when i am on the phone and click the button to expand the form it goes to the left of the screen an i can not read the form.

Comment: Now I understand what the problem is because the image control initially did not appear, So I thought the problem was only in response.
Now I'm trying to fix the problem, I will update the answer after completion.

Comment: Aِِlright, the problem in the script:

 $img_control.vAlign()
    //animate the form
    .toggleClick(function() {
      $mrova_feedback.animate({
        'right': '-2px'
      }, 1000);
    }, function() {
      $mrova_feedback.animate({
        'right': '-' + $mrova_feedback.outerWidth()
      }, 1000);
    });

You must change the value of  'right': '-2px'
I think -120 is very appropriate, try it and tell me the result

Comment: Changing it to -120 works but only half of the form slides in.